# Use Backbone.js router with #!

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

When using Backbone Router it will treat a "page" route as #page.

Can i make #! as default instead of just # ?

I would like to make html 4 browsers use #! (http://example.com/#!/page/subpage) and browsers with html5 history use normal address like http://example.com/page/subpage without having to use "!page" as the route.

"#!" is to make the ajax page crawlable. See http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ for more info.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I dediced to use the following approach:

```
//Create the Route without routes (just the functions)
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    "quem-somos": function() {
        alert("quem-somos");
    }
});
//test for html5 history using Modernizr and instantiate the Route with normal urls for true and prefixed routes for false 
if(Modernizr.history){
    App.routePrefix="";
    App.router = new App.Router({
        routes:{
            "quem-somos" : "quem-somos"
        }
    });
}else{
    App.routePrefix="!/";
    App.router = new App.Router({
        routes:{
            "!/quem-somos" : "quem-somos"
        }
    });
}
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
//Call navigate when clicking a button
    App.router.navigate(App.routePrefix+"quem-somos",{trigger: true, replace: true});
```

This way i get http://example.com/quem-somos and http://example.com/#!/quem-somos for each browser support.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the `!/` to your routes:

```
routes: {
  "!/help":                 "help",    // #!/help
  "!/page/:subpage":        "search",  // #!/search/kiwis
  "!/page/:subpage/p:page": "search"   // #!/search/kiwis/p7
},
```

Then, you will get the full `http://example.com/#!/page/subpage` url.

Comment: Oops, I guess I just read your entire question and realized that you don't want to change the routes because of push state. Sorry about that! Leaving this answer in case it helps someone else down the road.

Comment: It also works, but just like kpeel's answer, when using myRoute.navigate("page",true); the url fragment appears as # instead of #!;

Comment: Well, yes, because you have to pass the full route which would be: `myRoute.navigate("!/page",true);`

Comment: Ops! Sure! So it works. But for push state it gives the undesired !. A workaround would be to use Modernizr.history and give different values according to the result of the test.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Backbone.js source, it looks like the hash tag the`Backbone.History` module uses is hard coded in.

The easiest way to change this is to modify the source itself, on line 741 (Backbone 0.5.3):

```
var hashStrip = /^#*/;
```

Should be changed to:

```
var hashStrip = /^#!*/;
```

You also need to change the `navigate` function within `Backbone.History` to make sure "!" appears.  On line 863:

```
window.location.hash = this.fragment = frag;
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
window.location.hash = this.fragment = "!" + frag;
```

Unfortunately, due to how it was written in Backbone.js, I'm not sure there is a more elegant way to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer kpeel. Now Backbone recognizes the #! from the address, but when using myRoute.navigate("page",true);  the url fragment appears as # instead of #!;

Comment: Ah good catch.  Unfortunately this takes another edit of the Backbone.js source.  I'll update my answer with the change.